# How to Add a method to the model that takes JSON string and creates new records

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to Create two Django models: “Patient” and “Embryo”.

“Patient” properties:
First Name (string)
Last Name (string)
Telephone Number (string)
Email (string)
Created At (datetime)

“Embryo” properties:
Name (string)
Analysis Results (text)
Created At (datetime)
Patient’s Full Name
Patient (foreign key)

I now need to Add a method to the “Patient” model that takes JSON string and creates new “Embryo” records.
Here’s the JSON string:

```
[
{
"name": "embryo_1",
"analysis_results": "46,XX"
},
{
"name": "embryo_2",
"analysis_results": "47,XY,+21"
},
{
"name": "embryo_3",
"analysis_results": "46,XY"
},
]
```

**Below are my models that I created**
I am not sure how to add a method to the “Patient” model that takes JSON string and creates new “Embryo” records.

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    created_at =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)



class Embryo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
     analysis_result = models.Charfield(max_length=10)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def patient_full_name(self):
       return "%s %s" % (self.patient.first_name, self.patient.last_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an instance method to the model class, just like any other [python class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

- Load the `dict` from json string, (preferably, using [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)).
- Instantiate a list of `Embryo` objects.
- Pass the list to [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method to create multiple objects in one query.

**Example**:

```
import json

class Patient(models.Model):
    # fields

    def add_embryos(self, embryos_json_str='{}'):
        embryos = json.loads(embryos_json_str)

        embryo_objs = []
        for embryo in embryos:
            embryo_objs.append(Embryo(
                name=embryo['name'],
                analysis_result=embryo['analysis_results'],
                patient=self
            ))

        Embryo.objects.bulk_create(embryo_objs)
```

**NOTE**:

- You can wrap `json.loads` in a `try-except` block to not raise any unnecessary exceptions.
- If too many embryos objects in json, use `batch_size` argument of `bulk_create` to insert in batches.

Comment: How do I import `json` to add to the above code `embryos = json.loads(embryos_json_str)`

Comment: Oh. Missed that. Updating answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A method specifically to do this may not be necessary:

You can use python's `json.loads()` to load into a list of dictionaries, and then loop over to create the models.

```
import json
```

At the beginning of your file, then in your view:

```
#get the string from your request or form or wherever you get it
dict_list = json.loads('[{...}, {...}, {...}]'

for entry in dict_list:
    Embryo.objects.create(**entry)
```

the `(**entry)` syntax unpacks your `dict` into `kwargs`

Hope this solves your problem! :)